# Get custom title if category

Tags: categories

All of my categories has a custom single post title type, such:
"How to TITLE Free"
and then the article.

I want to get another title if category is News. So i won't have "How To TITLE Free" for single posts titles, but instead I will have "TITLE" only.

How can I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: how is that custom single post title type done? is that 'How to ... Free' added to the normal title via code?

Comment: yes, exactly. i am posting an article, and the title will automatically add "how to .... free" in it.

Comment: please post the code that automatically adds the 'how to ... free' to the title. you will need to add a condition to that code, that stops it from adding it if the post is in the 'News' category...

Comment: check the code: https://pastebin.com/7gCH5KTj (row 2)

Answer (score 1):

change this one line in your code:

```
<h1 class="article-title entry-title">How To <?php the_title(); ?> Free</h1>
```

to:
CORRECTION:

```
<h1 class="article-title entry-title"><?php if( in_category( array('news') ) ) { the_title(); } else { ?> How To <?php the_title(); ?> Free<?php } ?></h1>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/

Comment: Thank you, Michael. But seems to not work. I got this error: "There has been a critical error on your website. Learn more about debugging in WordPress" when trying to access any post.

Comment: apologies, there was an error in the code; I corrected my answer.

Comment: wow! it really works. Thanks a lot, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

use get_the_category() to get category of posts.
Compare it with your required category like:

```
$category = get_the_category();
if($category[0]->name == 'news') { 
   echo the_title();
} else {
   echo "title";
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This code is not working. Nothing changes.
So, for any single post in all of my categories I have a custom title like: "How To <?php the_title(); ?> Free"
I want to exclude "How To" on News category, and let <?php the _title();?> only

Comment: Can you share your entire code used on template??

Comment: this is single.php https://pasteio.com/xAxR4pebwEVK

Comment: url not working

Comment: check this one: https://pastebin.com/7gCH5KTj